# Unable to read text file with boolean grid into vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a text file which consists of boolean grid like structure as shown. Now, I am trying to read the text file into a `vector<vector<bool>> grid`. But I am unable to do so. My code is exiting without any error and execution is not moving inside the `while` loop.

Text file has below sample:

```
00000000000000001111111110000
000000100000000010100000100
0000000000000000111111111000
00000000000000011111111111000
0001000000000011111111111110
00000000000000011000000011000
00000000000000100010001000100
00000000000000100000100000
00100011111111111111111001110
00000000000011111000100000001
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<bool> >read_grid(const string &filename)
{
    vector<vector<bool> > gridvector;
    // Open the File
    ifstream in(filename.c_str());
    string str;
    bool tempb;// Check if object is valid
    if(!in)
    {
        cout<< "Cannot open the File : "<<filename<<endl;
        return gridvector;
    }

    // Read the next line from File untill it reaches the end.
    while (getline(in, str))
    {
        istringstream iss(str);
        vector<bool> myvector;
        while(iss>>tempb)
        {
            myvector.push_back(tempb);
        }

        gridvector.push_back(myvector);
    }

    //Close The File
    in.close();
    return gridvector;
}
 void display_grid(vector< vector<bool> >& grid) 
{
// this generates an 8 x 10 grid and sets all cells to ’0’
//vector<vector<bool> >grid(8, vector<bool>(10, 1));// printing the grid
    for(int x = 0; x < grid.size(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0;y < grid[x].size();y++)
        {
         // cout<<grid[x].size()<<'\n';
            cout << grid[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
   cout<<"grid at position [1][2] is: "<< grid[1][2]<<'\n';
}
int main ()
{
    const string b_file = "intial_grid.txt";
    vector< vector<bool> > grid_copy = read_grid(b_file);
    display_grid(grid_copy);
    return 0;
}
```

It is exiting with 'exit status -1'.

Comment: Where exactly do things start to go wrong? What happens if you don't use a separate function (consider [mcve])? Also, please format/indent your code consistently, preferably using an autoformatter. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I am not sure where it is going wrong but I see that control is not going inside while(iss<<tempb) at all

Comment: Check [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: An question, Could it be that the bits with 0 are ignored for optimization? and must we specify that we want to include them?

I had a similar problem and solved it this way

Comment: No @vincenzopalazzo ,I need to read all rows and columns of zeros and ones into a grid of vector

Comment: "*It is exiting with 'exit status -1'.*" - that means your code is crashing before it reaches the end of `main()`. Run the code inside a debugger and find out what is really happening

Comment: I am using online compiler but I will do debugging @RemyLebeau

Comment: can you post the display_grid() method, please?

Comment: I just did @vincenzopalazzo

Comment: Note `vector<bool>` is so different from a regular `vector` [that it gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Lot of gotchas in there.

Comment: In your case, `iss >> tempb` will fail as it is expecting a boolean value, i.e, a bit, but instead receives a string of 0s and 1s.

Comment: thanks @CaptainDaVinci any solution for this problem will be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String stream returns true on successful read and false on error.

In your case, `iss >> tempb` will fail as it is expecting a boolean value, i.e, a bit, but instead receives a string of 0s and 1s.

You can check this after first read `iss >> tempb`,

```
if (iss.fail()) {
    cout << "Failed to read\n";
}
```

You could instead iterate over the characters individually.

```
// Read the next line from File untill it reaches the end.
    while (getline(in, str))
    {
        istringstream iss(str);
        vector<bool> myvector;
        char bit;
        while(iss >> bit)
        {
            myvector.push_back(bit == '1' ? true : false);
        }

        gridvector.push_back(myvector);
    }
```

Comment: It is working thanks alot,I am able to get vector of vector with file read into it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given and accepted. The errors have been mentioned in the comments.

Anyway, I would like to show a "more" C++ approach, using std algorithms.

The idea is that we want to read a line with boolean values. So I designed a new data type, a class, that contains such data and also knows how to read it. In my humble opinion, the data and the methods should be packed in a class.

This will also reduce the lines of code in function main and overall drastically. In the definition of the variable and through the range constructor, all data will be read.

I added additional some debug output, so that the result can be visualized. Of course the access of the data using the index operator `[][]` will also work.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream testData(
R"#(00000000000000001111111110000
000000100000000010100000100
0000000000000000111111111000
00000000000000011111111111000
0001000000000011111111111110
00000000000000011000000011000
00000000000000100010001000100
00000000000000100000100000
00100011111111111111111001110
00000000000011111000100000001
)#");


// We want to have a data type for one line with boolean values in a string
struct Line {
    // We overwrite the extractor operator >> . With that we can easily read a complete line
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Line& l) { 
        std::string line{}; l.lineOfBool.clear(); getline(is, line);
        std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), std::back_inserter(l.lineOfBool), [](const char c) { return (c == '1') ? true : false; });
        return is; }

    // Type cast operator to expected value
    operator std::vector<bool>() const { return lineOfBool; }
    // The data
    std::vector<bool> lineOfBool{};
};

int main()
{
    // Define the variable that will hold all bool data of the complete file. The range constructor will read the file 
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> fileAsStrings{std::istream_iterator<Line>(testData),std::istream_iterator<Line>() };

    // For debug purposes: Copy all Data to std::cout
    std::for_each(fileAsStrings.begin(), fileAsStrings.end(), [](const std::vector<bool> & l) {std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

Please note: I do read from an istringstream, initilized with a raw string. So, no difference to reading from a file.

Maybe somebody finds this solution helpful.

Comment: Why not `std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), l.lineOfBool.begin(), [](const char c) { return (c == '1') ? true : false; });` that  way there is no need to call `l.lineOfBool.clear()` on every line.

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci. Correct. Thanks! Even Better!  +1

Answer (score 0):

The error 'exit status -1' is caused to *display_grid()* function, the components are vector and the access to the vector is **`verctorVariable.at();`**

another error is `while(iss>>tempb)` because your result is all row, your resolve this problem with this code

```
istringstream iss(str);
vector<bool> myvector;
string value;
iss >> value;
cout << value;
for(char c : value){
   cout << "**** debug print: " << c << endl;
   myvector.push_back((bool)(c-'0'));
}
gridvector.push_back(myvector);
```

also, your method ***display_grid()*** should be this

```
void display_grid(vector< vector<bool> >& grid)
{
// this generates an 8 x 10 grid and sets all cells to ’0’
//vector<vector<bool> >grid(8, vector<bool>(10, 1));// printing the grid

    for(int x = 0; x < grid.size(); x++)
    {
        cout<<"addin another elemen";
        for(int y = 0;y < grid[x].size();y++)
        {
             cout<<"addin another elemen";

            cout << grid.at(x).at(y);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //cout<<"grid at position [1][2] is: "<< grid[1][2]<<'\n';
}
```

This code return this exit code *Process finished with exit code 0*

Comment: but where am I pushing the bool values into myvector in the above code ?

Comment: Thank you for grid_display but the input code,I dont think it will be working to store bool values into vector

Comment: I don't think the `at` in `grid.at(x).at(y)` is useful here. The `for` loops guarantee that `x` and `y` are in bounds..

Comment: If you are going to read individual chars from a line, there is no point in using `istringstream` at all. You can iterate through the line directly : `for(char c : str)`